# SERVICE_NOT_AVAIBLE on GCM Android

Tags: android

I am having an issue with a terminal.

The point is that, I am able to connect with every devices but that one, and I don't understand why it is not working only with that device when there is Google_services installed and the internet connection is working properly......

This is my Manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="es.pruebas.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="es.pruebas.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name="es.pruebas.Aplicacion"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_app"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name="es.pruebas.ui.activities.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    <receiver
        android:name="es.pruebas.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="es.pruebas" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="es.pruebas" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="es.pruebas.GcmIntentService" />
</application>
```

Accordig to Google documentation, it tells me that I have to retry, and I retry 10 times with a difference of 1 sec each one, but anyway, this is only happening with this device, and not with the others I have been trying.

The terminal which is giving me problem is a Sony Ericson Xperia LT 26E, Android version 4.0.4...

Thnaks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution!

According to what I saw, Google has problems detecting the date and the time on terminals without SIM card and with "Automatic dates & time" activated, so when this is happening, I show a dialog to the user telling him to deactivate "Automatic dates & time" so that Google can get the time and the date from the system and the registration can continue without any problems.